# Database computed column not generating in EF 4.1

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a database table with a computed column

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PersonalityType]  AS ([dbo].[GetPersonalityType]([UserId]))
)
```

And a scalar function `[dbo].[GetPersonalityType]` that aggregates and filters data from another table. The computed value is not persisted in the database (because it is non-deterministic, I am told).

When I update the entity framework model from the database the computer column `PersonalityType` never shows up. What is wrong? Can EF 4.1 model computed columns in this situation?

Comment: What does your Entity Framework model look like? I'm assuming you are setting the StoreGeneratedOption to Computed - is that correct?

Comment: i ended up getting this to work. i dont know how. i played with a lot of properties and regenerated it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can get this to work, but try playing with a lot of properties and then regenerating it a lot.  ;-)

Comment: haha. you're going for the "only answer means you'll get the vote" angle, arent you?